# Qt Executable Failed?

Tags: c++, qt

I've finished my Qt application today and I switched between debug to release. When I try to run the program in release mode I get the following error:

```
An exception was triggered: Exception at 0x7c967406,code:
0xc0000135:DLL not found, flags=0x0.
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
```

Do I have to post a code sample? Can anyone tell me what's wrong or what do to? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all the qt.dlls in the folder of the release executable? Note that the dlls for release mode are called "qtXyyyy.dll" while those for debug mode are called "qtXyyyyd.dll" (X being the QT version, yyyy a module name). You need to place the right ones next to your exe.

Comment: There are no DLLS in the release folder.I'll search for them.Thanks!

Comment: You cannot mix debug and release builds. Switching to release from debug, it means you need to have all the libraries underneath in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your build then build it again.